# listbox items orientation to horizontal

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How to make the listbox items orientation to horizontal in the default styling of a listbox.
What i mean by default is the style which we get using blend.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the [ItemsPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemspanel(VS.95).aspx) property to replace the panel with a horizontal StackPanel:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

---

If you want to do this in a Style, just add a Setter that sets the ItemsPanel property:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox">
    <!-- Rest of the style -->
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: tx Quartermeister for the answer but i want to do this from style the default . I will just edit the style

Comment: hey Quartermeister tx once again but when done in style it throws me an error :
Message: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application Items collection must be empty before using ItemsSource.   at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.set_ItemsSource(IEnumerable value)

Comment: @Malcom: Its difficult to see how this could have broken it.  If you leave ItemsPanelTemplate property alone entirely, leaving as the default vertical stackpanel, do you still get the error?

Comment: oops sorry this error was for different issue..But it doesnt show up the data. His solution is rocking ..tx Quartermeister

Comment: I want to change the Orientation Horizontal to vertical dynamically based on page Orientation changed. Is it possible?